# angular 2.0.0 How to redirect after successfull login

Tags: angular, angular2-router3

I need to get from the router the prev URL (before the redirect to the login page)
Does the Router can give me the prev URL?

I found some old posts about this subject that are not relevant with the new stable router 3.0.0.

Comment: This should also work this._router.navigateByUrl(url)

Comment: Finding the prev URL is the real problem here, not the navigation process.

Comment: Are you using AuthGuard to specify which endpoints are secured ? If yes then for not logged in user pass the current location as a query string param to login component, when the login is done then navigate to the user to the query string param.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 2 latest docs. They still use this to navigate:

```
constructor(private _router: Router, private _location: Location) {}
this._location.back();
```

Have you tried?

Comment: I don't think back() will help me because I don't know if the user tried to go to a specific page before the app redirect him to login (then I need to go back there after success login) or the user just landed on the login page (then I will redirect him to the default home page after success login).

Comment: But when they are in home page and redirect to login. The back now is still Home and if they are in a specific page. The back is just that specific page. So what problem?